# creating custom indicators - each for every 4 item in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

so i have a content slider

each item has a class which contains offset of theat item in slider

like

```
<div id="slider">
     <div class="item item-num-1"></div>
     <div class="item item-num-2"></div>
     <div class="item item-num-3"></div>
</div>
```

and it's a circular slider , after last item it shows the first item again

so i've added custom indicators to the slider on the top but unlike most of sliders each indicators is for every 4 item in slider

```
for example

when i have 1-4 items theres is 1 indecitor 
when there are 1-8 items i have 2 indicators 
when there are 1-12 items i have 3 indicators
```

so i want to add the active class to the right indicator wehn user starts sliding

```
$(document).on('click' , '.prev , .next' , function(){


    var p      = $(this).parents('#slider');
    var it     = p.find('.item:first');
    var offset = Number(it.attr('class').split(' ').pop().replace('item-num-', '' ));

    var indicator_number ;

    if( offset <= 4 )
    indicator_number = 1 ;
    else
    indicator_number = ? ;


    $('.inidicator').eq( indicator_number ).addClass( "active" );


})
```

i want this part `indicator_number = ? ;` i want a formula to find right indicator when offset of current item is bigger than 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple arithmetic should get you what you need:

```
indicator_number = Math.floor((offset - 1) / 4) + 1);
```

`offset - 1`: get the zero based index of the current slide.
`/ 4`: divide
`+ 1`: change the result to a non-zero based index
`Math.floor`: convert to a whole number